# filtrar ultimo tres meses con Query google sheet

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

tengo la siguiente base de datos almacenada mediante un formulario diseñado con google app script,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy intendo filtrar con una funcion `Query` filtrar solamente los registros de los ultimos 90 dias (3 meses), investigue y una forma es de la siguiente

OPCIÓN 1:

```
=QUERY('BD'!A:S,"SELECT * WHERE (B >= date '"&TEXTO(AHORA()-90,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"')",-1)
```

OPCIÓN 2:

```
=QUERY({'BD'!A:A,arrayformula(IZQUIERDA('BD'!B:B,10)),'BD'!C:S},"SELECT * WHERE (Col2 >= date '"&TEXTO(AHORA()-90,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"')",-1)
```

OPCIÓN 3:

```
=QUERY({'BD'!A:A,arrayformula(TEXTO(IZQUIERDA('BD'!B:B,10),"yyyy-MM-dd")),'BD'!C:S},"SELECT * WHERE (Col2 >= date '"&TEXTO(AHORA()-90,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"')",-1)
```

Ninguna de las dos opciones me devulve algo, ambas vacio, supongo que es porque el `timestamp` esta guardado como texto, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Al ser texto solamente era necesario validar la fecha como texto.

```
=QUERY('BD'!A:S,"SELECT * WHERE B >= '"&TEXTO(AHORA()-90,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'",-1)
```